# Python Newton Raphson Decimal Roots

Tags: python, decimal, precision

I have this function (Newton-Raphson algorithm): 
"digits": desired precision of the root

```
from scipy.misc import derivative

def newtonDigits(function,xstart,digits):


    xprev=0
    ncalls=0

    while abs(xstart-xprev) >= 0.5 * 10**(-digits):

        ncalls +=1
        print xstart

        x = xstart - (function(xstart)/derivative(function,xstart,dx=1e-6))


        xprev = xstart
        xstart = x


    return xstart,ncalls
```

And input is :

```
f = lambda x: 14*x*(math.e)**(x-2) - 12*(math.e)**(x-2) - 7 *(x**3) + 20*(x**2) - 26*x + 12

root = newtonDigits(f,1.9,6)
print "Root: {0:.6f}".format(root[0])
print "Number of loops: N=" + str(root[1])
```

And output is:

```
1.9
1.9347284759
1.9570567413
1.97161234354
1.98117864941
1.98749755734
1.99168484127
1.99446528727
1.99631400887
1.99754426317
1.9983635866
1.99890940938
1.9992730728
1.99951577542
1.99967709739
1.99978645669
1.99985605669
1.99990268169
1.9999354436
1.9999606936
1.9999726936
1.9999806936
1.9999846936
newtonr.py:55: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
  x = xstart - (function(xstart)/derivative(function,xstart,dx=1e-6))
mainfile.py:6: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  f = lambda x: 14*x*(math.e)**(x-2) - 12*(math.e)**(x-2) - 7 *(x**3) + 20*(x**2) - 26*x + 12
inf
Root: nan
Number of loops: N=24
```

I tried to use Decimal but i have problem with floats and lambda function.
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newton-Raphson does not work well for a root where the derivative is zero. That is the case in your problem, as this graph shows.

[image]

In fact, any root where the derivative is zero is difficult to get with great precision, and that holds for any numeric root-finding method. Your case is even worse, since both first and second derivatives are zero at the root. This means the function's graph is very close to a straight horizontal line at the root. Given that, it will be difficult to get better precision than one-third the total number of significant digits. Most computers will give double precision, about 15 digits, so much more than 5 significant digits will be difficult. Your routine already gives that, so don't expect much better from any numeric routine.

You especially get the problem as you take the precision in your derivative to `1e-6` (the parameter in your `derivative()` call) and the problems come when your x-value gets to the same precision in x.

You could use some variant of Newton-Raphson to avoid this and other problem--remember that Newton-Raphson is not guaranteed to converge in the general case and has multiple difficulties. Take at look at `rtsafe` in the book *Numerical Recipes* as a safe usage of N-R (Newton-Raphson).

If you want to stick very close to N-R you can modify your code to check the value of the derivative before calculating the next value of x. Just stop the loop when the derivative becomes zero.

If you really want more precision in a case like yours and use straight N-R, you need a better calculation of the derivative. You are using a numeric derivative that apparently is not very good. That numeric derivative is probably giving a second-order result, using the symmetric difference of two points around the evaluation point, and that is not good enough here. You could use a more sophisticated derivative routine that uses more points and gives a higher-order result. But in your case the function is simple enough that you can write your own function that gives a good derivative to your original function. Just use basic calculus rules up to the product rule. In fact, any actual Newton-Raphson routine should be given a function that calculates the derivative and you usually should *not* use an approximated, numeric derivative unless necessary. One could argue that using a numeric derivative means that you are not actually doing Newton-Raphson and you should use another method to find the root--the book *Numeric Recipes* does in fact make this point.

Modifying your code to use a defined derivative function, as well as cleaning up some of your style, gives

```
import math

def newtonDigits(function, dfunction, xstart, digits):
    xprev=0
    ncalls=0
    while abs(xstart-xprev) >= 0.5 * 10**(-digits):
        ncalls +=1
        print(xstart)
        x = xstart - function(xstart) / dfunction(xstart)
        xprev = xstart
        xstart = x
    return xstart, ncalls

f = lambda x: 14*x*(math.e)**(x-2) - 12*(math.e)**(x-2) - 7*x**3 + 20*x**2 - 26*x + 12
df = lambda x: 14*x*(math.e)**(x-2) + 2*(math.e)**(x-2) - 21*x**2 + 40*x - 26

root = newtonDigits(f, df, 1.9, 6)
print("Root: {0:.6f}".format(root[0]))
print("Number of loops: N=" + str(root[1]))
```

which prints

```
1.9
1.9347284749567717
1.9570567399626235
1.9716123428786936
1.9811786535860885
1.987497587688875
1.991684850749086
1.9944652840851569
1.9963140403238206
1.9975443983678638
1.9983636880398847
1.998909460162945
1.9992731216554642
1.9995154801019759
1.9996770218573676
1.999784687490283
1.9998564592822783
1.9999043185996854
1.9999363386081155
1.9999575985093117
1.9999719257797395
1.999982068293325
1.9999875928805002
2.00000490230375
Root: 2.000005
Number of loops: N=24
```

Comment: Yes, the problems come when  x-value gets to the same precision in x. But i believe that is not the same x  the next x..  I want more precision..

Comment: i changed the "1e-6" to "1e-5" and the result is 1.99999953083

Comment: A numeric derivative routine is quirky and can give strange precision, thanks to the combination of approximation error that shrinks with lower tolerance and round-off error that grows with lower tolerance. See my extensive addition for a better way to improve your routine. Be aware, however, that any root where the derivative is zero is difficult to get with great precision, and that holds for any root-finding method. My point about avoiding numeric differentiation for Newton-Raphson holds.

Answer (score 0):

If you print the value of `x` and the `derivative` in each step you will see:

```
1.9347284759 0.0683501539811
1.95705673873 0.030810070939
1.97161234728 0.0138147377982
...
1.99997209174 1.42108547152e-08
1.99997909174 7.1054273576e-09
inf 0.0
nan nan
```

We can see that the derivative gives us zero, and dividing by zero gives us inf.

If you use a larger dx converge. For `dx=1e-3`

```
...
1.99991975788 2.71786149142e-06
1.99992026519 2.7172077921e-06
1.99992075954 2.7165576455e-06
Root: 1.999921
Number of loops: N=95
```

Comment: Ok , but why the derivative is zero? i believe that isn't zero, maybe the precision is not good...